# How to use COUNT alias in SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-optimization

I get an error for the below query:

```
SELECT 
    mt.tag_id,
    count(mt.tag_id) as bcount,
    bcount / t.count as rel,
    t.count as t
FROM
    tags.media_tag as mt,
    tags.tags as t
WHERE
    mt.media_id in (SELECT 
            mt.media_id
        FROM
            tags.media_tag as mt
        WHERE
            mt.tag_id = 'tag')
GROUP BY mt.tag_id
ORDER BY rel
LIMIT 1000;
```

Error:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'bcount' in 'field list'
```

I'd like to use the count in the select again as it is quite an expensive query. I can just do `count(mt.tag_id)` but that seems to be unbearably slow. Any ideas to optimize or achieve alias with the count?

Tables:

`medias` (shown for completeness, not needed in query)

```
+----+-------+-------+---------+
| id | attr1 | attr2 | attrEtc |
+----+-------+-------+---------+
| 11 |       |       |         |
| 22 |       |       |         |
+----+-------+-------+---------+
```

`media_tag`

```
+----------+--------+
| media_id | tag_id |
+----------+--------+
|       11 | tag    |
+----------+--------+
```

`tags`

```
+-----+-------+
| id  | count |
+-----+-------+
| tag |     1 |
+-----+-------+
```

**UPDATE**: Sample Data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8085

Expected Response where target tag, or in query above `mt.tag_id = tagB`:

```
+--------+--------+--------+-----------------+
| tag_id | tcount | bcount | bcount / tcount |
+--------+--------+--------+-----------------+
| tagB   |      2 |      2 | 1               |
| tagC   |      2 |      1 | 0.5             |
| tagA   |      3 |      1 | 0.333           |
+--------+--------+--------+-----------------+
```

bcount = number of shared media_id between tag_id and tagB (target)

Comment: In the given fiddle what would be your `mt.tag_id = 'tag'` ? value from query that you have ? Also one of the reason for your query to be slow is `order by` clause on a calculated value this makes query really slow when there is a large number of data.

Comment: Answered this in update would be just 'tagB'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query I ended up using. @NoDisplayName got close but not all the way there. This SQL actually completes running in seconds and is much much faster than my original query.

```
SELECT 
    mt.tag_id,
    COUNT(mt.tag_id) / t.count as rel,
    COUNT(mt.tag_id) AS bcount,
    t.count as tcount
FROM
    tags.media_tag AS mt
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        smt.media_id
    FROM
        tags.media_tag as smt
    WHERE
        tag_id = 'tag') meds ON mt.media_id = meds.media_id
        INNER JOIN
    tags.tags t ON t.id = mt.tag_id
GROUP BY mt.tag_id
ORDER BY rel;
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `alias` directly use the `Count(mt.tag_id)`

```
SELECT mt.tag_id,
       Count(mt.tag_id) AS bcount,
       Count(mt.tag_id) / t.count AS rel,
       t.count          AS t
FROM   tags.media_tag AS mt,
       tags.tags AS t
WHERE  mt.media_id IN (SELECT mt.media_id
                       FROM   tags.media_tag AS mt
                       WHERE  mt.tag_id = 'tag')
GROUP  BY mt.tag_id
ORDER  BY rel 
LIMIT 1000;
```

**Update:** Try changing your query like this. You can avoid the `sub-query` in `where` clause and use proper `Inner Join`

```
SELECT mt.tag_id,
       Count(mt.tag_id)           AS bcount,
       Count(mt.tag_id) / t.count AS rel,
       t.count                    AS t
FROM   tags.media_tag AS mt
       INNER JOIN tags.tags AS t
               ON mt.tag_id  = t.id
WHERE  mt.tag_id = 'tag'
GROUP  BY mt.tag_id
ORDER  BY rel
```

Comment: Will MySQL detect it as the same operation, the query is very very slow.

Comment: @Zaheer - Updated check now. Join both the tables using common column

Comment: This seems mostly there but only returns 1 result always. The idea is to return all other tags with a relation to the target tag.

Comment: @Zaheer - From which table you need to return all the rows. Can you explain a bit more

Comment: Added sample query / result to question

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing mistake here....
correct it bcount to count(mt.tag_id)

```
SELECT 
        mt.tag_id,
        count(mt.tag_id) as bcount,
        count(mt.tag_id) / t.count as rel,
        t.count as t
    FROM
        tags.media_tag as mt,
        tags.tags as t
    WHERE
        mt.media_id in (SELECT 
                mt.media_id
            FROM
                tags.media_tag as mt
            WHERE
                mt.tag_id = 'tag')
    GROUP BY mt.tag_id
    ORDER BY rel
    LIMIT 1000;
```